# Why does the screen flash when I log into Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, display

When I log in with Windows 8.1 the screen flashes for one second, turns black and then continue booting windows normally.

I scanned for viruses without detecting anything. It is not a problem of the video card because it only happens on that occasion.

Does anyone know the cause?

Comment: so it turns black for one second then displays normal again? Just to clarify

Comment: yes, you got it.

Comment: I guess I don't know if this is normal Windows 8.1 behavior or not since I don't have it. Not really a big deal though but I guess for you its just more of an annoyance?

Comment: it's not a normal behaviour, i've a laptop with win 8.1 and it boot up fairy. And yes it's a little annoying

Comment: Your question is vague. Is this a new problem? Can you tell us more about the computer itself? How do you know it isn't a driver issue? Maybe that is when the driver is loading.

Comment: Did screen flashes when you disconnect from session `tsdiscon` and then connect to it again?

Comment: @CharlieRB how i can check if it's a driver issue?

Comment: It is really impossible to troubleshoot this over the web.  It could be the monitor is slow when changing resolutions.  Or it could be a video related driver is loading in the background.  everything would be a guess.

Comment: @Keltari i know, probably it's a driver, but without formatting it's possible to check it?

Comment: You still haven't answered if this is a new problem? Or has it always done it?

Comment: @CharlieRB no it's a new problem. I suppose it came out when i installed windows updates..

Comment: You can view your update history to see if the driver was updated. If it was, roll it back. Otherwise, you can try a System Restore to a date before the update.

Comment: Sounds like Windows switches resolutions twice. It sometimes does that when loading the profile, so there’s no malware involved.

Comment: A workaround: use Sleep [but not Hibernate, which had issues in Windows 8/8.1] to resume quickly. That should be much faster than resuming from Shutdown (which is actually a partial hibernate), and **much** faster than starting after full shutdown or Restart.